# how to connect to SQL database in MVC6 ASP.NET 5 with DB first approach without migrations stuff

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net5

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{


    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
        builder.AddUserSecrets();


        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc();
services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();


    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");


        try
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                .CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                     .Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseIdentity();

    // To configure external authentication please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}


public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

I have a Model and my start up class in ASP.NET 5 + MVC 6  look like this. I want to connect my already created Database Table to the application.As it is already created, it would not go for migration .. How to do this in MVC6 + ASP.NET 5

Comment: Did you checkout this docs page? http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

Comment: yah I had gone through this one.. it will be helpful for me if anyone knows how to connect SQL Server without EF 7 ? can we do it with sql string using Data Adapters within MVC6+ ASP.NET5??